# How to make vscode to "go to definition" for js code which is embedded in HTML files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have most of my javascript code in  tags in HTML files. How can I make vscode to make it 'go to definition' for js functions made in these files. This feature is present in other IDEs like RubyMine. So this should be present in vscode also.

Comment: Do you have Chrome debugger installed? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome

Comment: No I don't have that installed.

Comment: You need to use it to debug JS in html files

Comment: Actually I just want to go to definition of functions while developing. This works if functions are in js files. but if it is in <script> tag it is not working.